# Is there a way to cleanly remove a very old commit from git tree?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-filter-branch

**TL;DR:** there is a 6 year old commit and I just want it gone, I believe it is empty and I'd like to have it removed.

i.e. the commit at the very bottom:

```
[a few thousand commits on top of this]
*   08d01075 - (5 years ago)
|\
| *   2da4e798 - (5 years ago)
| |\
| |/
|/|
* | f29c0523 - (5 years ago)
* | a9a851d7 - (5 years ago)
* | d8e70b9b - (5 years ago)
| *   84a54eff - (5 years ago) new branch 
| |\
| |/
|/|
* | 022bca02 - (6 years ago) 
* | 79a5d079 - (6 years ago) 
* | 5a89f05a - (6 years ago) 
* | f02cc7f0 - (6 years ago) 
* | 645ffc64 - (6 years ago) 
* | 9693b596 - (6 years ago) 
 /
* 55555555 - (5 years ago) the null commit
```

The 55555555 is the one I wish to remove

I do not know how real this commit is, because of this:

```
$ git diff 55555555^ 55555555 
fatal: ambiguous argument '55555555 ^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Or

```
$ git show --no-patch  2bb15d71
commit 5555555
Author: .........
Date:   Tue Mar 12 11:01:54 2012

the null commit
```

Comment: ...Why?  What good would removing that (and then changing **every single commit that follows it**) really do for you?

Comment: As Makoto states, the way git hashes are calculated means that removing this commit would require recalculating hashes for every subsequent commit. You really do need a good reason to do this as it will invalidate every other copy of the tree.

Comment: the only discernible good that I can see is to be more appealing to my soul and my sense of neatness.  If it requires tearing everything down I suppose it may not be worth it

Comment: Switch to CVS. It allows you to do dirty hacks with repository.

Comment: The fact that `555555^` doesn't exist doesn't mean `55555` is not a real commit. It means it is the _first_ commit, so has no parent. Just use `git show 55555` to see what - if anything - is in it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't actually want to do this, as mentioned in the comments.

But If you are sure that you do, you can run an interactive rebase:

`git rebase -i --root`

`-i` is a switch for interactive rebase.

`--root` is the first commit ever.

Delete the line of the commit that you want to remove, and save.

The issue with this technique is that the commit will remain on other contributors machines, and will be pushed to the remote repo when they make a change unless they follow the same steps you have. If you are working alone this should work.

Comment: It's not a good idea to do this with `git rebase -i --root` for another reason: rebase can't copy merge commits, and removes all merges by default. Adding `--preserve-merges` tries to re-perform merges but this plays poorly with an actual edit of `pick` commands in an interactive rebase, so that's actually even worse. :-)